# python - Replace several different characters by only one

Tags: python, regex, string, replace, character

I'm looking for a way to replace some characters by another one.

For example we have :

> chars_to_be_replaced = "ihgr"

and we want them to be replaced by

> new_char = "b"

So that the new string

> s = "im hungry"

becomes

> s' = "bm bunbby".

I'm well aware you can do this one char at a time with .replace or with regular expressions, but I'm looking for a way to go only once through the string.

Does the re.sub goes only once through the string ? Are there other ways to do this ? Thanks

Thanks

Comment: how does the string.replace() not work for you?

Comment: With replace you have to go through the string for each character you want to remove don't you ?

Comment: No you don't. `import re; re.sub("[ihgr]", "b", "im hungry")`

Comment: Well, that's not the .replace()

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`string.translate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.translate)

```
from string import maketrans

chars_to_be_replaced = "ihgr"
new_char = "b"
s = "im hungry"

trantab = maketrans(chars_to_be_replaced, new_char * len(chars_to_be_replaced))

print s.translate(trantab)
# bm bunbby
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
chars_to_be_replaced = "ihgr"
new_char = "b"

my_dict = {k: new_char for k in chars_to_be_replaced}

s = "im hungry"

new_s = ''.join(my_dict.get(x, x) for x in s)
print(new_s)  # bm bunbby
```

`''.join(my_dict.get(x, x) for x in s)`: *for each letter in your original string it tries to get it's dictionary value instead unless it does not exist in which case the original is returned.*

---

> NOTE: You can speed it up (a bit) by passing a `list` to `join` instead of a generator:

```
new_s = ''.join([my_dict.get(x, x) for x in s])
```

Comment: I've only tested on this small example but it takes more time than to use four times replace. Need to use it on more representative examples